# Application of Geometric Sequence 2

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the 10th term of a geometric sequence whose first term is 3 and whose 6th term is $\sqrt{3}$$/9$.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: No worries, I know there's a lot of rules and norms to get used to on a new site. Just wanted to give some tips.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A geometric progression is a sequence of the form
$$a,\;ar,\;ar^2,\;\ldots$$
Thus, the first term is $a$, the 6th term is $ar^5$, and the 10th term is $ar^9$. Solve for $r$ using the information given, then conclude.

Answer (score 1):

The general term $a_n$ of a geometric series is given by $a_n=ar^{n-1}$. According to your problem $a_1=a=3$ and $a_6=\sqrt 3/9$. Calculate $r$ from this. Then calculate $a_{10}=ar^9$.